# What is wrong with my DNS entries?

Tags: domain-name, domain-registration

I have some problems with a domain not working as expected. My registrar's controlpanel shows these records for mydomain.eu:

```
www A 111.222.333.444
* A 111.222.333.444
```

I use the nameservers of my registrar.

I get a correct answer if i do

```
dig www.mydomain.eu  
dig whatever.mydomain.eu
```

I can also ping/visit website etc with those adresses. But,

```
dig mydomain.eu
```

wont resolve to anything. I just get this:

```
    ; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R1 <<>> mydomain.eu
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 46837
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.eu.   IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mydomain.eu.  1799 IN SOA ns1.binero.se. registry.binero.se. 1281647822 3600 240 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 77 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan  6 01:36:31 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 83
```

The same A-record setup work for another domain/server ip, but that domain has other nameservers. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

That means you have no A record for just mydomain.eu. *.mydomian.eu won't match just mydomain.eu. You need something like:

```
    A 111.222.333.444
www A 111.222.333.444
* A 111.222.333.444
```

Then a query for just mydomain.eu should work.