# Server unreachable without www

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost, host

My server is unreachable without "www." prefix, even when trying it with `ping`.

The DNS entry looks like this:

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN SOA ns1.first-ns.de. postmaster.robot.first-ns.de. (
    2011010600   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    86400 )      ; minimum

@                        IN NS      robotns3.second-ns.com.
@                        IN NS      robotns2.second-ns.de.
@                        IN NS      ns1.first-ns.de.

@                        IN A       1.2.3.4
localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
mail                     IN A       1.2.3.4
www                      IN A       1.2.3.4
ftp                      IN CNAME   www
imap                     IN CNAME   www
loopback                 IN CNAME   localhost
pop                      IN CNAME   www
relay                    IN CNAME   www
smtp                     IN CNAME   www
@
```

A DNS record of the same type for another domain on the same server is working with and without "www".

And the VirualHost config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName somewhere.com
        ServerAlias www.somewhere.com

</VirtualHost>
```

An nslookup for www.somewhere.com and somewhere.com shows different IPs! The wrong IP is from a former version of the DNS record. Maybe some DNS servers are not up to date, but I wonder why they are up to date with the www. version.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Increment the serial after adding the default record to the zone? can you ping somewhere.com? Or try nslookup or dig on somewhere.com and check the record.

Comment: Can you do an nslookup for the name both with and without? What response do you get back?

Comment: Did you change your DNS recently? Check with your ISP (whoever "owns" the IP block your server is on).

Comment: This may help: http://serverfault.com/questions/219470/what-is-wrong-with-my-dns-entries

Comment: Maybe the change hasn't propagated? try an nslookup or dig directly against your nameserver

Comment: @USACASD he has an A record for the domain, though

Comment: Use a dig or nslookup and send dns query to AUTHORIZED DNS server

Comment: @Ency not necessarily. knowing the output of the server is just as useful as knowing the state of the world, and could identify a problem such as a fail to reload the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to incrementing the serial, as Chris S said in a comment, one small step often overlooked by those who don't work with DNS routinely is telling the DNS server to reload the file.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you only need the A record for www to resolve.

```
Hostname  IP Address 
           1.2.3.4 
mail       1.2.3.4 
www        1.2.3.4
```

Comment: The problem is that the domain doesn't resolve _without_ www, not with it

Answer (score 0):

Since almost all answers came in form of comments, I have to repeat a comment to answer the question.

The solution was: Increment the serial after adding the default record.